# VB.net - CDATE rsData

Tags: vb.net

I'm doing the following to try and determine whether display a course online based on whether its in the future or would have started in the last 30 days.

```
If Date.Today.AddDays(-30) >= CDate(rsData("Start")) then
html += "<tr><td>" & rsData("Start") & "</td><td>" & rsData("WEEKS") & "</td><td>" &
rsData("DAYSTIME") & "</td>
```

However this doesn't seem to work and blocks for instance the following rsDATA(("Start")) value.

2012-09-10 00:00:00.0000000

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic is backwards, try this:

```
        If Date.Today.AddDays(-30) <= CDate(rsData("Start")) Then
            'in last 30 days, or the future
        End If
```

Comment: I should stop coding today as its not going well!

Thanks for the clarification and yes I can see that this would work compared to my initial attempt.

Many Thanks!